# How to convert a nested dictionary into matrix list?

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array, nested-lists

i have the following dictionary

```
dictionary = {'test1.txt': {'apple': 1, 'banana': 1, 'lemon': 1},
'test2.txt': {'apple': 1, 'banana': 1},
'test3.txt': {'apple': 1, 'lemon': 2},
'test4.txt': {'apple': 1, 'lemon': 1, 'grape': 1}}
```

i want the output to be

```
[['', 'apple', 'banana', 'lemon', 'grape'],
['test1.txt',1,1,1,0],
['test2.txt',1,1,0,0],
['test3.txt',1,0,2,0],
['test4.txt',1,0,1,1]]
```

The way i am trying is that

```
testcasenumber = dictionary.keys()  // here i got all the test.txts
```

i am new to python and kinda stuck in how to proceed forward with my solution.

Comment: A simple google search yields a lot of results. For example, https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-flatten-nested-dictionary-to-matrix/

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, i checked that but found it bit different

Comment: i agree with your stand point , i could have added complete information, Sorry about it, if i ever were to post a question again, i will definately keep all your suggestions and write in a more effective way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you would get all the column names:

```
from collections import ChainMap
header = ["", *ChainMap(*d.values())]
```

And then you can just write a for-loop:

```
result = [header]
for k, v in d.items(): 
    row = [v.get(h, 0) for h in header] 
    row[0] = k 
    result.append(row)
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using the common `pandas` library?

```
from pandas import DataFrame

dictionary = {'test1.txt': {'apple': 1, 'banana': 1, 'lemon': 1},
              'test2.txt': {'apple': 1, 'banana': 1},
              'test3.txt': {'apple': 1, 'lemon': 2},
              'test4.txt': {'apple': 1, 'lemon': 1, 'grape': 1}}

df = DataFrame(dictionary).fillna(0).transpose()
result = [['']+list(df.columns)] + list([idx, *values] for idx, values in zip(df.index, df.values.astype(int).tolist()))
print(result)
```

Result:

```
[['', 'apple', 'banana', 'lemon', 'grape'], ['test1.txt', 1, 1, 1, 0], ['test2.txt', 1, 1, 0, 0], ['test3.txt', 1, 0, 2, 0], ['test4.txt', 1, 0, 1, 1]]]
```